# Weak* convergence of measures

Tags: measure-theory, weak-convergence

Suppose we have a sequence $\mu_j\rightharpoonup\mu$ weakly* in $M^+(\overline{\Omega\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{B}^N})$, where $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ is open, bounded, $\mathbb{B}^N$ is a unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^N$, $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is a two-point compactification of the real line. $M^+(X)$ is the space of positive measures on $X$.

Suppose further that $\mu_j,\mu$ do not charge the set $A:=\overline{\Omega}\times\{\pm\infty\}\times\overline{\mathbb{B}^N}$, i.e. $\mu_j(A)=\mu(A)=0$ for all $j$.

I want to prove that for any $f\in C(\overline{\Omega}\times\mathbb{R}\times\overline{\mathbb{B}^N})$ we have $$\langle f,\mu_j\rangle\to\langle f,\mu\rangle.$$ So far I have figured out, that for $f\geq 0$ the inequality $$\langle f,\mu\rangle \leq \liminf_{j\to\infty} \ \langle f,\mu_j\rangle$$ holds. Any insight would be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save ink, write $X=\overline\Omega\times\mathbb{R}\times\overline{\mathbb{B}^N}$ and $\overline X$ = its compactification $\overline\Omega\times\overline{\mathbb{R}}\times\overline{\mathbb{B}^N}$.
You have $\mu\rightharpoonup\mu$ in $M^+(\overline X)$ and want to check it in $M^+(X)$ as well.  The measures involved do not charge $\overline X \backslash X$.

I suppose $\mu\in M^+(X)$ is regular, so for $\epsilon>0$ there is a compact $K\subset X$ such that $\mu(K)>1-\epsilon$. Let $L\subset X$ be another compact set, with $K\subseteq \mathrm{interior}(L) \subset L  \subset X$. Let $f:\overline X\to [0,1]$ equal $1$ on $K$ and vanish off of $L$. Then $\langle f,\mu_j\rangle \to \langle f,\mu\rangle \ge 1-\epsilon$.  Hence the sequence $\mu_j$ is tight in $M^+(X)$.  So weak* limits of $\mu_j$ exist in $M^+(X)$.  That the limit is unique follows from the convergence of $\langle f,\mu_j\rangle \to \langle f,\mu\rangle$ for every $f\in C(X)$ of compact support.

Comment: I think that the regularity definition you use applies to the probability measures, but that shouldn't be a problem. Anyway, big thanks!

Comment: @Quincunx Whoops!